# List all the scheduled performSelector:withObject:afterDelay : for an object

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

Given an `NSObject` instance is there a way to list all the selector that has been scheduled for that object with the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method (or related)?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, you'll need to keep track of the calls yourself, or use your own NSTimer to send delayed messages.

If you're trying to cancel messages for specific selectors or targets, you can use [`cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget_selector_object_)